# Heroku custom server for uploads

Tags: wordpress, heroku, ftp, vps

I was wondering, is it possible to mount own server host, just for uploads and static files ?
Something like the aws S3, but custom solution (Own VPS) ?

I'm mean if they can build the addon, why won't it be possible to create own addon ?